# VBA - pin a row under dynamic range

Tags: vba, dynamic, static, range, row

I'm looking for solution in *VBA*,  that will stick/pin a 4 cell range under dynamic range. By that I mean that sometimes the dynamic range is 5 rows and sometimes it's 10 rows. I need a row that's summing values from dynamic range and it should be directly under dynamic range. If dynamic range ends on 5th row, the summing row should be 6th etc.

I would be grateful for any kind of support in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly. The following script adds all values from Cell A1 to the LastRow and print the result one Cell below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    'get the number of the last row    
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    'sum up all values and write the result below the last row
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
    Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1)))

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm newbie in VBA and I don't know how exactly use this code in mine existing one.

Comment: Sub CalcToPackingList()
    
    With Sheets("Calc")
        .Range("A1:E1", .Range("A1:E1").End(xlDown)).Copy Sheets
("PackingList").Cells(22, 3)
    End With
    
End Sub

It is a part of the code that creates a list in destination sheet. I need to put my static range under dynamicly created list. Let say, that this range with formulas can be anywhere, but it would be grate if i could leave it in place and just putting my generated list between heading row and summing row.

Comment: Am i right that you want to copy Range("A1:E1") to the Cell(22,3)
and now the Cell(22,3) should be dynamically too?

Comment: Not exactly, I'll try to clear it up. I've got sheet1 from I'm copying some of data to sheet2. In sheet2 data is beeing sorted/cleared up and so on. Than, from sheet 2 this data in correct order is being copied to destination sheet (let say sheet3). BUT this set of data could be 3 rows, sometimes 5 rows and the other day 10 rows. And than afret insterting this set in Sheet3 I need to add automatically summing row exactly under this set.

Comment: I hope that you can fully understand me now.

Comment: That's exactly what I need!! I just need to edit it for specific cells. I really, really appreciate your help. Hope some day I'll know VBA better... :)

Comment: glad I could help and for learning VBA, the macro recorder is a great tool :)

Comment: I've just checked it again in my specific rows, columns etc. It works perfectly. Once again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can find last row using this for example:

```
LastRow=Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Maybe this is the way to go. Can you tell me how to - for example - paste my specific data to LastRow variable you showed?

Comment: `Sheet1.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = Variable` where `Variable` is Your specific data

Comment: This will paste value in first collumn